# if statements with different regular expression parameters

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Hi I am trying to read tags on a list of words, the list has words like (TMConnects(MEN) what(WP) happened(VB) to(TO) your(ADV) my(ADV) tm(N) website(N) i(N) can(ADV) access(N) to(TO) view(N) my(ADV) bills(N) ) I am trying to use if statements and regular expressions to read each tag so I can categorise the words appropriately.

Here is the code I tried

```
 foreach (string word in tokensList)
        {
            //Verbs
            Match match_verb = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(vb\)");
            if (match_verb.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word + "v");
                Verbs.Add(word);
            }
            else
            {
                //Nouns
                Match match_noun = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(n\)");
                if (match_noun.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word + "n");
                    Nouns.Add(word);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Adverb(Ad)
                    Match match_adverb = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(adv\)");
                    if (match_adverb.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(word + "adv");
                        Adverbs.Add(word);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Adjective(Adj)
                        Match match_adj = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(adj\)");
                        if (match_adj.Success)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(word + "adj");
                            Adjectives.Add(word);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Mention(Men)
                            Match match_men = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(men\)");
                            if (match_men.Success)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(word + "men");
                                Mentions.Add(word);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Object(KNK)
                                Match match_obj = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(knk\)");
                                if (match_obj.Success)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(word + "obj");
                                    Objects.Add(word);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Features(KT)
                                    Match match_feature = Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(kt\)");
                                    if (match_feature.Success)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(word + "ft");
                                        Features.Add(word);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Please help me.

Comment: What help are you expecting? One thing I can suggest is that the input `word` can be belong to only one category at a time but not more than one. Hence you can use `if-else` loops instead of nested `if-else` loops,

Comment: Help you with what?  You didn't tell us what isn't working.  Are the tags in upper case, as in your example?  Regex is case sensitive by default (without `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`).  It seems like it would be cleaner to have a single regex to extract the word and tag, and switch on the tag, or perhaps have a dictionary with the tags as the key and the list as the value?

Comment: I am trying to read the tags on the words and then later categorize the words, but the problem it seems some of the if statements are simply ignored. for example with the list of words I gave above it should have found them all and printed them out but it only finds ( my(adv)adv
website(n)
can(adv)
my(adv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to lowercase all of the text between the brackets from the list you've provided, I get all the correct results back. So, I'm going to assume the problem is as [Mark suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967196/if-statements-with-different-regular-expression-parameters#comment69144061_40967196): you have a problem with your regex being case sensitive and to fix that all you have to do is provide the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option.

So instead of `Regex.Match(word, @"[a-zA-Z]+\(vb\)")`
it would be something like this `Regex.Match(word, @"[a-z]+\(vb\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`.

However, following Marks suggestions once more, you are most likely approaching the problem in a way that's catered too much for a specific solution. That is, instead of having an if-else statement for each condition (attempting to perform a regular expression match each time), you could perform a single match using a more generic regular expression and utilize the tools .NET provides to come up with a more flexible solution.

```
    foreach (var match in
        tokensList.Select(
            word =>
                // Two capturing groups: "word" (unnecessary in your case) and "type", 
                // where "word" contains the word only (e.g. TMConnects) and "type" contains the type only (e.g. MEN).
                Regex.Match(
                    word,
                    // Match any letters appearing one or more times followed by an opening bracket ('('), anything that 
                    // isn't a closing bracket and a closing bracket (')').
                    @"^(?<word>[a-z]+)\((?<type>[^\)]+)\)$", 
                    // Tell the regular expression engine to ignore the casing.
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    // Filter out words that don't match the regular expression.
                    .Where(match => match.Success)) 
    {
        // The whole word (including the type.
        var word = match.Value;
        // The type lower-cased, for convenience.
        var type = match.Groups["type"].Value.ToLowerInvariant();
        switch (type)
        {
            case "vb":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "v");
                Verbs.Add(word);
                break;
            case "n":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "n");
                Nouns.Add(word);
                break;
            case "adv":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "adv");
                Adverbs.Add(word);
                break;
            case "adj":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "adj");
                Adjectives.Add(word);
                break;
            case "men":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "men");
                Mentions.Add(word);
                break;
            case "knk":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "obj");
                Objects.Add(word);
                break;
            case "kt":
                Console.WriteLine(word + "ft");
                Features.Add(word);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @eitamal but the problem still persists, some words are totally ignored for example the words tm(N) website(N) i(N)  access(N)  view(N) bills(N) are all nouns and thus should have been added to the nouns list but when I do a print out in that list it only contains the word website, I do not understand why it is skipping all the other words, the loop should go through all of them.

Comment: And see if you can pinpoint the problem you're experiencing. My guess would be that the token list is a bit different than the one I'm using.

Comment: You are amazing, this actually helped me solve my problem!